# How can I make Windows Photo Viewer (8) move to the next subfolder when at the end of one like Photos (10)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-gallery, windows-photo-viewer

Something like this:

```
Main Folder
    Subfolder 1
        Image 1
        Image 2
        Image 3
    Subfolder 2
        Image 1
        Image 2
        Image 3
```

In the Windows 8 Photo Viewer (The one where the icon is the classic XP background framed and blue), when you press right arrow at S1 I3, you'll go to S1 I1, and in Windows 10 Photos (the one with the black and white mountain icon), when you press right arrow at S1 I3, you'll go to S2 I1, although at S2 I3 it won't loop around, but that's a different question. How do I get the Windows 8 Photo Viewer to go to the next subfolder instead of looping within the same subfolder? Thank you for your help, I'm not the best with computers.

Comment: See if the registry edit here helps.. ignore the title. [Fix Windows Photo Viewer Opens Multiple Windows When Multiple Files are Selected in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-photo-viewer-instances-multiple-files-previewed-windows-10/)

Comment: That works!(!!)[!!!] How on earth did you find that?

Comment: Gr8.  Years of tinkering work with Windows is helping :o)